# Upload and read file

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, apache-poi

I want to upload the file contains "text/image" (example: Articles) to s3. then want to read that file from s3 and want to show on website.

so, what is the best format for file from which i upload it to s3..and read easily the text or images from file to show on website.

Technologies : Java spring-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what is the best format for file from which i upload it to s3?**

It's depends on your project requirement.In which format you need to store the file on S3. S3 can accept any file format for storing.

**How to read easily the text or images from file to show on website?**

After storing the file on S3 you can access the specific document by using the URL of the document which is generated by S3.You can get the url of document on AWS S3 console or you can use S3 Browser for accessing the url.
Below is sample url which will generate.
**http://esdoc.s3.amazonaws.com/0/11/164/1.pdf**

You need to use  html tag for showing the Images(.png,jpg,jpeg) and for pdf you need to use  html tag.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav..can you please tell me .pdf .txt which is better for my requirement

Comment: It totally depends on your business requirement.We store it in pdf format.

Comment: For Images in pdf what would i do?

Comment: Finally you will get pdf right? Then show it as a pdf.